# AspectJ throws BCException "visiting a false expression"

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aspectj

The project I am working on uses aspectj weaver 1.9.7

It is used with the `@Configurable` on hibernate entity classes.

When starting the project I randomly get `BCException: visiting a false expression` when trying to weave an entity class. The entity is not always the same, and the error does not always happen.

Do you know what could cause such an error?

```
[localhost-startStop-1] org.aspectj.weaver.tools.Jdk14Trace.error my/package/FailingHibernateEntity
    org.aspectj.weaver.BCException: visiting a false expression
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelRenderer.visit(BcelRenderer.java:203)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.ast.Literal.accept(Literal.java:29)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelRenderer.recur(BcelRenderer.java:110)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelRenderer.renderTest(BcelRenderer.java:100)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelAdvice.getTestInstructions(BcelAdvice.java:702)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelAdvice.getAdviceInstructions(BcelAdvice.java:527)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelShadow.getAfterReturningAdviceDispatchInstructions(BcelShadow.java:1806)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelShadow.weaveAfterReturning(BcelShadow.java:1719)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelAdvice.implementOn(BcelAdvice.java:365)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.Shadow.implementMungers(Shadow.java:645)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.Shadow.implement(Shadow.java:547)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.positionAndImplement(BcelClassWeaver.java:1662)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:510)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelClassWeaver.weave(BcelClassWeaver.java:103)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1707)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveWithoutDump(BcelWeaver.java:1651)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weaveAndNotify(BcelWeaver.java:1418)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWeaver.weave(BcelWeaver.java:1192)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.getWovenBytes(WeavingAdaptor.java:549)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.WeavingAdaptor.weaveClass(WeavingAdaptor.java:385)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.Aj.preProcess(Aj.java:115)
        at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.transform(ClassPreProcessorAgentAdapter.java:51)
        at org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler$AspectJClassBypassingClassFileTransformer.transform(AspectJWeavingEnabler.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2382)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:870)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1341)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1195)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:130)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.<init>(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.<init>(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:164)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:158)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4705)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5171)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1176)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1917)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I do not remember this exception in any situation. Please publish a minimal reproducer ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) on GitHub, ideally a Maven project. If you need a data source in ordfer to reproduce this, make sure it is an in-memory database like H2 which is preconfigured, so I can just run the example and see the error. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's probably not gonna be easy to build an MCVE, as the problem does not always happen, but I'll give it a go. As different builds/environments behave differently, I am thinking it is probably not a problem with aspectj itself. But to get to the source of the problem, I need to understand why aspectj is rendering Tests (what's a Test in that context) and what could cause it to render a Literal test.

Comment: @kriegaex I could not find documentation about test rendering in aspectj, if it exists and you could point it to me, that would be super appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I never worked on that part of the code before, so I cannot answer your question without digging into it, which I am too busy for at the moment. I do not think you need to understand the inner workings of AspectJ in order to create an MCVE. If you manage to create one, please let me know. Maybe you also want to test if upgrading to AspectJ 1.9.9.1 changes the situation, even though I am unaware of any changes in that part of the code. An upgrade might help if you are using [more recent JDK versions](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/docs/dist/doc/JavaVersionCompatibility.md).

Comment: So? Is the problem no longer relevant?

Comment: Thanks for following up on this. The problem is still relevant, but I did not manage to create a minimal reproducer yet, and with my current load I won't be able to work on that anytime soon. I'll reach out here or on github if I manage to reproduce the issue reliabily. Thanks